# Trying to make lottery add role to player

Tags: node.js, discord, discord.js

I am trying to make a lottery command give a role to a player I have no clue why it is not working I have been trying to figure it out please help me fix it thank you, (by the way the role name is the same with caps and everything in the code).

code in .js file:

```
const Discord = require("discord.js");
const bot = new Discord.Client();

module.exports = {
    name: 'lottery',
    description: 'MAYBE YOU SHALL WIN?!?!',
    execute(client, message, args) {
        var role = message.member.roles.cache.find(role => role.name === "Lucky Winner");
        const lottery = Math.floor(Math.random() * 1) + 1;
        if (lottery === 1)
            return message.reply(`Wow! You actually won! Great job! :white_check_mark: ` + message.member.guild.roles.add(role));
        message.reply(`Nope, sorry, you lost. ❌`);
    }
}
```

code in main.js file:

```
else if(command === 'lemmewin') {
    client.commands.get('lemmewin').execute(client, message, args);
}
```

console error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'execute' of undefined
```

Comment: The problem seems to be coming from this `client.commands.get("lemmewin")`. How it `commands` generated? Have you forgotten to add your module to it?

Comment: You call `client.commands.get('lemmewin')` even though the command's name is `lottery`. Try `client.commands.get('lottery')` instead.

Answer (score 0):

It means that there exists no command with name `lemmewin`. So in your case it should be `client.commands.get('lottery').execute(client, message, args);` because you have your command name set as lottery in the module `name: 'lottery'` and not `lemmewin`.

Comment: Ohhhhhhhhhhhhhh